# How get marker position before dragging?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In Google Maps API v2, I want to store the previous location before dragging a marker, however, when I begin dragging the marker, it will always jump to some upper location, so in callback `onMarkerDragStart`, I can't get the last position.

Is it a bug, or can any fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

the fact that the marker "Jumps" is because otherwise you could not see the marker due to the finger over it.
In order to get the marker position, you should keep it saved before start dragging. The documentation is pretty clear:

> Called when a marker starts being dragged. The marker's location can be accessed via getPosition(); this position may be different to the position prior to the start of the drag because the marker is popped up above the touch point.

So the idea is to keep the position "cached" and get them from this cached variable when dragging starts.

Comment: Problem is I have 100s of markers placed inside map. I don't ideally want to cache it.

Comment: I see, unfortunately there is no method, but anyway, you cache only the position, not the whole marker... I'm sorry but there is no available API for this, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

An example that may solve your question

```
function makeMarker(iPos) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: iPos,
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        zIndex: 1001 
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        iPos = marker.getPosition();
    });         
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {    
        console.log("Position after dragging: ", event.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
        console.log("Position before dragging: ", iPos.toUrlValue(6));
    });     
}
```